# Iterating over list, reusing certain values several time in csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I have some data looking like this:

```
description "export"
source "factory1"
source "factory2"
source "factory3"
destination "customer1"
destination "customer2"
shipdate "asap"

description "export"
source "factory4"
source "factory5"
source "factory6"
destination "customer1"
shipdate "30"
```

I am now trying to create a csv file where it looks something like this:

```
description,source,destination,shipdate
export,factory1,customer1,asap
export,factory2,customer1,asap
export,factory3,customer1,asap
export,factory1,customer2,asap
export,factory2,customer2,asap
export,factory3,customer2,asap
export,factory1,customer1,asap
export,factory2,customer1,asap
export,factory3,customer1,asap
export,factory4,customer1,30
export,factory5,customer1,30
export,factory6,customer1,30
```

The data blocks are handed to me as python lists, so I am currently iterating over them in a look and then based on the first word putting them into other lists. There is likely a much starter way of handling it however.

So far my code looks something like, but as you can see that wont solve my problem:

```
sourcelist = []
destlist = []
for item in list:
  if "source" in item:
    sourcelist.append(item)
  if "destination" in item:
    destlist.append(item)
```

Grateful for any help! Even if it means I need to rewrite the code!

Comment: Why are some values like `export,factory1,customer1,asap` repeated twice?

Comment: You are effectively asking for a parser to a format you have not specified. Does your data look *like* this or do you have some additional rules to follow? What are they?

Comment: @MarkMeyer The data is repeated twice since it is two different blocks, just to show you that there is not always two destinations.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi A hint in the direction on how to approach this also would be appreciated :) However, there are really not many rules. Destinations can be up to two, but no more. Sources can be any number. Description is always there and so is shipdate. Wierd, I know, but that is what I have to work with

Comment: @xeet how the list is look like [description "export", source "factory1", ... ,shipdate "asap"]?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi the list looks like this: ['export', 'source factory 1', 'source factory 2', 'source factory 3', 'destination customer 1', 'destination customer 2', 'shipdate asap']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each individual line is not sufficient by itself, data must be accumulated. According to your description and sample, you can do this block-wise. Simply accumulate *all* fields of a block - unique fields will just have a single item.

You parse the blocks efficiently with a generator:

```
def parse_blocks(source: 'Iterable[str]'):
    block = {}
    for line in source:
        if not line:  # delimiter between blocks
            yield block
            block = {}
        else:
            key, value = line.split()
            block.setdefault(key, []).append(value.strip('"'))
    if block:
        yield block
```

This gives you an iterable of blocks, such as

```
{'description': ['export'], 'source': ['factory1', 'factory2', 'factory3'], 'destination': ['customer1', 'customer2'], 'shipdate': ['asap']}, ...
```

For each block, you want all combinations across fields. The [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) provides this out of the box.

```
import itertools

def merge_lines(blocks: 'Dict[str, List[str]]', *fields: 'str'):
    for block in blocks:
        yield from itertools.product(
            *(block[key] for key in fields)
        )
```

This provides the data of individual lines as an iterable of tuples:

```
('export', 'factory1', 'customer1', 'asap'), ('export', 'factory1', 'customer2', 'asap'), ...
```

You can feed this directly to `csv`, or process it any way you see fit.

```
import csv
import sys

fields = 'description', 'source', 'destination', 'shipdate'

writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)  # or write to a file, pipe, ...
writer.writerow(fields)
for data in merge_lines(parse_blocks(input_list), *fields):  # insert your input here
    writer.writerow(data)
```

This produces the desired csv output:

```
description,source,destination,shipdate
export,factory1,customer1,asap
export,factory1,customer2,asap
export,factory2,customer1,asap
export,factory2,customer2,asap
export,factory3,customer1,asap
export,factory3,customer2,asap
export,factory4,customer1,30
export,factory5,customer1,30
export,factory6,customer1,30
```

Comment: Really helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import itertools

# setup test data
raw_data_1 = ['description export', 'source factory 1', 'source factory 2', 'source factory 3', 'destination customer 1',
  'destination customer 2', 'shipdate asap']

raw_data_2 = ['description export', 'source factory 4', 'source factory 5', 'source factory 6', 'destination customer 1',
   'shipdate 30']

# create list of input data
data_list = [raw_data_1, raw_data_2]


# collect data from string
collected_data = []
for item in data_list:
    description = 0
    source_data = []
    destination_data = []
    ship_date = 0
    for data in item:
        if 'description' in data:
            description = re.sub('description ', '', data)
        elif 'source' in data:
            source = re.sub('source ', '', data)
            source_data.append(source)
        elif 'destination' in data:
            destination = re.sub('destination ', '', data)
            destination_data.append(destination)
        elif 'shipdate' in data:
            ship_date = re.sub('shipdate ', '', data)

    # create combinations
    combination_data = list(itertools.product(source_data, destination_data))

    # extend combinations data
    for item in combination_data:
        out = [description] + list(item) + [ship_date]
        collected_data.append(out)


# past data into data frame
data = pd.DataFrame(collected_data, columns=['description', 'source', 'destination','shipdate'])

# save data to file
data.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

```
  description     source destination shipdate
0      export  factory 1  customer 1     asap
1      export  factory 1  customer 2     asap
2      export  factory 2  customer 1     asap
3      export  factory 2  customer 2     asap
4      export  factory 3  customer 1     asap
5      export  factory 3  customer 2     asap
6      export  factory 4  customer 1       30
7      export  factory 5  customer 1       30
8      export  factory 6  customer 1       30
```